# Using withStyles of material-ui v1 in a nested manner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have this component that I am trying to write in react manner. Where each of the major containers are separated as React class component. 
Now I know how to use withStyles with one component :
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);

But when you have more than two components, how do you use withStyles.
Here's the code :

```
    class AtmanPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AtmanAppBar />
    );
  }
}


class AtmanAppBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className= {this.props.classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className= {this.props.classes.menubutton} color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={this.props.classes.flex}>
            Title
          </Typography>
          <Button color="contrast">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    width: '100%',
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
});

export default withStyles(styles) AtmanPage ?;
```

Now the question mark is about what else should be done to pass the styles as a prop to AtmanAppBar through AtmanPage.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to `withStyles` but in the way you organize your components and exports.

**Solution 1:**

You can put each component in a separate file and use

```
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

in each file as you have mentioned in your post.

**Solution 2:**

You can do a simple export for both of your classes if you wish to keep them in the same file:

```
export const StyledAtmanAppBar = withStyles(styles)(AtmanAppBar);
export const StylesAtmanPage = withStyles(styles)(AtmanPage);
```

Then you need to import them like so in another file:

```
import {StyledAtmanAppBar, StylesAtmanPage} from './path/to/your/file';
```

Comment: yeah I know that, but the problem is that one major component contains 8,9 sub components or classes resulting in a lot of files. 
Is that good ?  **@klugjo**

Answer (score 0):

Looking to handle this shizzle myself I came across a helpful util to use Styled-Components™-like API via Material-UI.

[Gist example](https://gist.github.com/vadistic/2db4254e7e3c0b29960d9a4256ffffc4/)

After importing it as:

```
import styled from '../utils/styled';
```

you can create many Styled-Components-lookalikes in one file:

```
const List = styled('ul')(theme => ({
  padding: theme.spacing.unit,
  margin: 0,
}));
```

One difference with default `withStyles()` API is, that this util applies the styles to the `root` class, so you cannot nest many styles styles for one component (probably could be easily upgraded to allow that tbh).

But it's really handy for simple styles re-usability without the need to create too many files.

[Credit to the (probable) author](https://github.com/danielmahon)